# Cannot select some items in the wpf listview

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm using wpf lisview as

```
<ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="System Name" Width="Auto"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SystemName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Network Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SystemComputerName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SystemIPAddress}"/>                    
                </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I have added few rows to the list. The problem is I cannot select with mouse rows 3 and 4. I can select those rows using keyboard but not by mouse. Nothing happens when I click on those rows. I tried to move data between 3rd and 1st rows but of no use. Sometimes I can select row 3 if I keep on clicking data at various column positions.

Any clues?

Update: sorry its my problem. I have a label control that is diaplayed on list which has empty text.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Is there perhaps a transparent ui element that overlaps part of the `ListView`?

Comment: Thanks Brain. Very good thinking.

Comment: Have you solved it yet? Show more XAML.